# docker-compose config leads to "LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE" for Kafka / Zookeeper

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, kafka-consumer-api

Here is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.9'

services:

  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    container_name: 'virl-zookeeper'
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    container_name: 'virl-kafka'
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'false'
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

I exec into the kafka container with:

```
docker exec -it 'virl-kafka' /bin/bash
```

and I run this command:

```
[appuser@03d1893a77f4 ~]$ kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --from-beginning --topic 65879c8b4dcc7c77f19acc2f
```

and I get this output:

```
[2023-12-24 02:51:52,815] WARN [Consumer clientId=console-consumer, groupId=console-consumer-45321] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 2 : {65879c8b4dcc7c77f19acc2f=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2023-12-24 02:51:52,936] WARN [Consumer clientId=console-consumer, groupId=console-consumer-45321] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 4 : {65879c8b4dcc7c77f19acc2f=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2023-12-24 02:51:53,061] WARN [Consumer clientId=console-consumer, groupId=console-consumer-45321] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 6 : {65879c8b4dcc7c77f19acc2f=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

anyone know what that `LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE` thing is about?

This 65879c8b4dcc7c77f19acc2f is one of my topicIds - do I need to declare a leader for every topic or something? Since my topics are dynamically created, that would be hard.

Comment: The config is fine. Starting a consumer doesn't create a topic. Therefore, there's no partition leader to consume. So, where did you create a topic? Also, you'd typically use the service name, not container name for compose exec